# Put nested div to left side of screen

Tags: html

Lets say I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="divOuter">
    <div id="divInner"></div>
</div>
```

Let's also say that the outer div is about 3/4 down the page, centered on the screen (horizontally), and has a width of 200px.  Obviously the inner div would be initially at this position.  How can I keep the inner div at the same vertical position (which is currently is), but move it all the way to the left of the screen?

Answer (score 3):

Position `divInner` absolutely and set the left propery to zero:

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y4NUu/)**

Comment: ok but what if you want the inner div to be the same size as the outer div?

Comment: Well you can either explicitly set the dimensions or use JavaScript to do it, but once you position it absolutely it won't remember the dimensions of the container it was in.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I'm trying to accomplish using just pure CSS?

Comment: If you can't set the dimensions of the inner div with CSS then no.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some CSS to it. However the only way I know uses fixed positions so for example:

```
    .position{
     position: relative; left: -20px;
      }
```

Then in your div

```
<div id="divInner" Class="position"></div>
```

Would be 20 pixels to the left

Answer (score 0):

You can give `#divInner` an absolute left position but leave its top position to auto;

```
#divInner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

This assumes that `#divOuter` is not absolutely positioned itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this HTML...

```
<div id="divOuterWrapper">
    <div id="divOuter">
        <div id="divInner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this CSS?

```
#divOuterWrapper {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}

#divOuter {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:300px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    min-height:50px;
}

#divInner {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    min-height:30px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:50%;
    left:-50%;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Qfq3/1/

Comment: I'd like to have the inner div's width be dynamic with the outer div

Comment: You could always set the width of the two like this `#divOuter, #divInner { width:200px; }`